# Finding all of the values in a lookup field in SharePoint Online with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

So I've been having a hell of a time with this. I'm using the SharePoint PnP module to try automate some SharePoint tasks.

Essentially I am trying to add a new item to a list that has lookup fields. The sticking point I have now is trying to add a lookup field value that does not yet exist in the list but it exists in the lookup field.

I can't seem to find a way to capture what exists in the lookup field itself, just what currently exists in the lookup field in the list.

```
$List_SkillsPerAgent = Get-PnPList -Identity SkillsPerAgent

$DCISkill = (Get-PnPListItem -List $List_SkillsPerAgent -Fields "wsp_ucc_spa_skill").FieldValues.wsp_ucc_spa_skill | Where-Object { $PSItem.LookupValue -eq 'DCISkill' } | Select-Object LookupId -First 1

$PhoneQueue = (Get-PnPListItem -List $List_SkillsPerAgent -Fields "wsp_ucc_spa_skill").FieldValues.wsp_ucc_spa_skill | Where-Object { $PSItem.LookupValue -eq $Queue.Replace('_', ' ') } | Select-Object LookupId -First 1

$Agent = (Get-PnPListItem -List $List_SkillsPerAgent -Fields "wsp_ucc_spa_Agent").FieldValues.wsp_ucc_spa_Agent | Where-Object { $PSItem.LookupValue -eq 'sip:somefakeemail@domain.com' } | Select-Object LookupId -First 1
```

The first two steps work fine because those values already exist in the list, however the last one 'sip:somefakeemail@domain.com' does not exist in the list yet so I can't find its LookupID with Get-PnpListItem, however it does already exist in the lookup field wsp_ucc_spa_Agent.

I tried messing around with Get-PnpField but no such luck yet.

Is there anyway to capture all of the values in that lookup field?

Answer (score 1):

The values in the lookup field are stored in the parent list you refer to. To capture all of the values in lookup field. I would suggest you find them in the parent list, the lookupID should be the listItem id in parent list.

Comment: I've done some more digging in the parent List item, I was thinking it would be in here `$List.Fields` but I was given this error `An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested..` I'm still thumbing through the available properties, methods, etc. Am I looking in the right spot?

Comment: You could try this for parnet list to get field values: (Get-PnPListItem -List <Parent List>-Fields "FiekdName").FieldValues

Comment: That is what I am doing, but it won't grab values of the lookup field that don't yet exist in the list. That is what I am attempting to do. For example, there is a lookup field with Value1, Value2, and Value3 in it. However only Value1 and Value2 exist in the list. Is there any way to get all values of the lookup field even if they don't exist in the list?